# IIS7 authentication

Tags: security, iis, iis-7, authentication, .htaccess

To give our user's the ability to protect content on their IIS6 sites we used a tool called IISPassword which emulates `.htaccess` to provide Basic authentication.

There isn't support for IISPassword on IIS7 at the moment. Is there an equivalent mechanism I can use built into IIS7 instead?

I'm well aware of ASP.NET Forms Authentication, but I need a way for users deploying non-ASP.NET content (such as PHP, Perl, images etc) to be able to use Basic authentication but not have to write code to achieve this.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Hey Kev.  Yes, with IIS7, system.webServer allows users to lock down sections and have it apply to all types of content.  It's "similar" syntax to the ASP.NET system.web syntax.  You can use IIS 7 Manager to change it, then look at the resultant web.config to get the syntax.

Comment: haven't ignored/forgotten about this answer, just haven't had the time to go play with this yet.